# Interpreting HRs from stratified cox survival analysis in R

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

In the R code below, `binary_variable_2` has two levels (e.g. "a" and "b").

The code outputs only one HR for `binary_variable_1`. Is this HR a combination of two HRs (i.e. one from each strata of `binary_variable_2`) or something else? If it is a combination, how are the strata specific HRs combined (in simple terms)? If it is something else, what is it?

```
coxph(Surv(time_to,event)~binary_variable_1+strata(binary_variable_2),data=dat)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Cox model with a covariate $X$ is defined as
$$
\lambda(t \mid X) = \lambda_0(t) \exp \left( \beta X \right)
$$

where $\lambda_0(t)$ is the baseline risk and $e^\beta$ is the hazard-ratio.

A Cox model stratified upon a categorical variable $Y$ with $k$ modalities is a Cox model where a different baseline risk is used for each group:

$$
\lambda_k(t \mid X) :=\lambda(t \mid X, Y=k) = \lambda_{0k}(t) \exp(\beta X)
$$

The assumption is that the effect of $X$ (the hazard-ratio) is same across each group but the baseline risks are different between those groups.

For example say $X$ is a binary treatment and $Y$ is also binary and encodes the age ($\geq 50$ vs $<50$).

Then the model assume that:

- the effect of the treatment is the same no matter if the patient is older than 50 or not.
- the baseline risk of getting an event is different between the two groups (e.g. people older than 50 have a higher risk)

---

Note that a stratified Cox model is different than a model where each group have its own hazard-ratio:

$$
 \lambda(t \mid X, Y=k) = \lambda_{0}(t) \exp(\beta_k X)
$$

because then since $\beta_k= \beta_j + \beta_k - \beta_j$

\begin{align*}
 \lambda(t \mid X, Y=k)&=\lambda_0(t)\exp(\beta_j)\exp(\beta_k-\beta_j) \\
&= \lambda(t \mid X, Y=j)\exp(\beta_k-\beta_j) 
\end{align*}

Thus the risks between two groups, $$\frac{ \lambda(t \mid X, Y=k)}{ \lambda(t \mid X, Y=j)}=\exp(\beta_k-\beta_j) $$
will be proportional, which may not be the case with the stratified Cox model since the baseline risks $\lambda_{0k}(t)$ and $\lambda_{0j}(t)$ are not assumed to have any particular proportional relashionship.